# Reading and parsing a json file

Tags: python, json

I'm using the following python script to read and parse a json file

```
import json

with open('testdata.json', 'r') as raw_data:   

  content = json.load(raw_data)  
  print(content)
```

that has data like:

```
    {"grp":"1"; "total":"10"}  
{"event":"run", "timestamp":"2010-01-30 10:00:40", "id": "200", "distance": "5"}  
{"event":"walk", "timestamp":"2010-01-31 18:46:00", "id": "200", "disrance": "2"}
```

I'm getting the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "readdata.py", line 4, in <module>  
    content = json.load(raw_data)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 290, in load  **kw)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 369, in decode  
raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))  
ValueError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 3 column 1 (char 93 - 187)
```

If I have one row of data it works... 2 or more rows of data I get the error

Can't see anything that is causing this problem

Comment: As traceback said pretty explicitly, your json data is badly formated. `{grp:1; total:10}` needs double quotes for keys. I'm not sure if json require a striped data too, but anyway, removing the leading tab is a good thing too

Comment: @Arount Missing double quotes is the least of the issues with the file formatting (Missing `[ ]` to denote top-level list and missing `,`)

Comment: @DeepSpace surely, but it was the first i saw, I think now we pointed out this is a formatting issue he could be able to fix it alone anyway

Comment: Thanks for the assist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SO syntax highlighter solved your issue.

```
"distance': "5"}
         ^
```

Change this to double quotes

But there are many other issues. here is a valid version of your json file.

```
[
  {"grp":1, "total":10},
  {"event":"run", "timestamp":"2010-01-30 10:00:40", "id": "200", "distance": "5"},  
  {"event":"walk", "timestamp":"2010-01-31 18:46:00", "id": "200", "disrance": "2"}
]
```

Note the `"` arround each key. the `,` between `key:value` pairs, and the `,` between elements of the list.

You can validate your JSON using tools like [jsonlint.com](https://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: The file I have contain rows of json data as shown... Are saying that I have to add the braces to make it an array?

Comment: If you want you file to be a valid json file, yes

Comment: That was it!!... Thanks!!